# How to pass ngRepeat "template" to a ngDirective using transclude?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/TiH96FCgOGnXV0suFyJA?p=preview

I have a ng-directive called myDirective and within the directive template I have a list of li tags printed using ng-repeat. I want to declare the content of li tag as part of the declaration of myDirective and use transclude to print the desired text / html content. This way I can have a nice separation of concerns so that my directive doesn't need to know the structure of the source item, and it'll be the caller's responsibility to layout the content of li.

Something like below:

```
<my-directive source="vm.source">{{label}} and {{id}}</my-directive>
```

or even

```
<my-directive source="vm.source"><a href="#{{id}}">{{label}}</a></my-directive>
```

The template of ngRepeat (inside myDirective) looks like

```
template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in source" ng-transclude></li></ul>',
```

But I can't get the transclusion to work inside hg-repeat. I am using the latest version of angular 1.2.19. To be precise, the trasnclusion works but not the expression I am passing in at directive level.

Please help and thanks heaps!

I couldn't come up with a better question title. You are welcome to make it better.

Update: I chose the answer by @pixelbits because that's what I was asking for. But I actually used approach by @Norguard because it is more angular way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transcluded contents are compiled against a child scope of your parent scope (also known as transclusion scope, but this is not the same as your directive's isolated scope). That being said, you can specify the template in your parent HTML (although it is a bit outside of the normal use case in angular) and manually compile it against your directive's isolated scope.

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController as vm">
      <my-directive source="vm.source">
        <span>{{item.label}} and {{item.id}}</span>
      </my-directive>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Notice that the inner HTML of my-directive references 'item' which must be defined in the directive's scope.

**Directive**

```
function directive($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            source: '='
        },
        compile: function(element, attr) {
          // in the compile phase, remove the contents 
          // of element so that it is not compiled by angular.
          // We will be manually compiling it in the link function.
           var template = angular.element('<ul><li ng-repeat="item in source">' + element.html() + '</li></ul>');
           element.empty();

           // link function
           return function(scope, element, attr) {
             // append the template
             element.append(template);

             // compile and link the template against the isolated scope.
             $compile(template)(scope);
           }              
        }          
    };
}
```

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QrnkOouAjbmNSg8BPOB5?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! I like this approach. Also I'm taking consideration of what @Norguard have recommended. I need to go read some more docs about angular though.

I see on the angular doc there's a "new" way of doing compile. Would your approach work with this "new" way? Just wondering. Thanks. 
function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) { ... }

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: I didn't realise the "whole directive template" needs to be compiled "manually".

Comment: @Jeff The reason it is difficult to do with transcludeFn is because you need the child scope that ng-repeat creates on an item-by-item basis. You can't just use the isolate scope. The above solution works because we are modifying the entire template and not just the transcluded contents.

Comment: @Jeff this is something you'd want to do for binding MasonryJS / Isotope, or for D3 graphing, but grabbing a single span, to pull out the names of the fields, to hand-prep the compile (or defer in a closure, to do it all manually during linking, and suffer a next-tick render penalty) just for populating an `ng-repeat` is a bit much. Like I said, Angular lets you do it any way you'd like. Equally viable is a `pluck` function which can be passed to prep each item, to feed into a new list, in the `link`, to have Angular populate a list (next-tick, again). It's about complexity vs goals.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff, your transcludes are a little backwards.

Or, moreso, the way transcludes work is a little backward, compared to how you think they do.

If you have a transcluding directive, and you put content inside of it, the content is reading from the parent of the transclude directive, and not the directive itself.

For your example, assuming :

```
<div ng-controller="parentController as parent">
    <transcluding-directive>
        {{ key }} {{ val }}
    </transcluding-directive>
</div>
```

There are two problems, here.

The first problem is that ng-transclude is a sibling to the content it transcludes.
Both of them would use `parent` as their parent-scope.
The transcluded content doesn't read data from inside of the transcluding directive.
This is again that separation of concerns, thing; if the transcluding directive had the same property names as the content you were transcluding, that would overwrite the transcluded content, and cause all kinds of weird behaviour, so they're siblings.

For all intent and purpose, under the covers, it might behave like this:

```
<transcluding-directive></transcluding-directive>
<div>{{ transcludedContent }}</div>
```

Then, the content would be pulled up, and appended to the node found by `transcludingDirective.querySelector("[ng-transclude"])`.

That's really not the exact workings of it, but it is the result you get (short of you doing your own compiling/transcluding routines, in the directive).

The second error is a little more obvious, when you know the first error:
{{ label }} and {{ id }} of `vm` are properties on `vm`'s `$scope` object.

They don't exist on that `$scope`, and are therefore `undefined`, which is why you get `'' + 'and' + ''` out of your templates.
You are creating an `<li>` for each of the items passed to the directive, but you are interpolating `undefined` and `undefined` for each of them.

The directive you've written should either be a specialized directive (one that knows how to build that exact kind of list),

```
<specific-list-maker items="vm.list"></specific-list-maker>
```

or a general directive, which you feed the list into

```
<generic-drawer>
    <ul><li ng-repeat="item in vm.list">{{item.label}} {{item.id}}</li></ul>
</generic-drawer>
```

...it could even be a specific directive which knows how to feed more generic directives, inside of its template...

```
 <specific-list items="vm.list"></specific-list>

 <!-- specific-list.html -->
 <generic-drawer>
     <generic-toggle ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.label }} {{ item.id }}</generic-toggle>
 </generic-drawer>
```

This is the composition that Angular (and Polymer, and in the future, Web Components, themselves) lends itself well to.

As a simple example from a project that I've been working on, I've got elements that filter down, something like this:

```
<page-type-a></page-type-a>

<!-- page-type-a.html -->
<card-collection cards="page.items"></card-collection>

<!-- card-collection.html -->
<header ><!-- ... header stuff --></header>
<card ng-repeat="card in cards"></card>

<!-- card.html -->
<header><h1>{{ title }}</h1></header>
<blockquote>{{ content }}</blockquote>
<cite>{{ author }}</cite>


<page-type-b></page-type-b>
<!-- page-type-b.html -->
<card-collection cards="page.items"></card-collection>
```

Each component doing little more than its own job.

There are other ways of getting this to work (feeding in a "key" attribute and a "value" attribute, and functionally plucking the values out of each item in the list to compose your own internal list, for your `ng-repeat`...   ...or preparsing the values from the transcluded content, prior to linking your `$scope` instance to the transcluding-directive's inner template, before inserting it into DOM...)  ...but doing that, in this case is just about as crazy as it sounds.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess I need to read a bit more on angular. I actually had what I wanted working but in a different way. I pass in a formatter function from controller to the directive which pumps out the desired format for each li. But I thought it would be more declarative (angular way) to do what my question is trying to solve. Thanks for your answer, I will dig a bit deeper into angular.

Comment: @Jeff It's absolutely possible to do. You can hook into almost any part of Angular and bend it to your will. But the code gets a lot simpler when you compose your directives to wrap other directives, versus writing large pre-comp or post-transclude, pre-linking functions, or "=" function overrides (parent-to-inner-directive references), et cetera.  There are certainly times where it's easier/necessary (like integrating D3.js or Masonry.js, etc), but it's not something that lends itself to ease of use/reusability, as much as simply building lego blocks and arranging them on the page.