# Transclude partial content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a "sticky table header" component for which I need to copy parts of the transcluded content of my directive.

Depending on how I transclude the content, it works only partially at best: with `$compile`, expressions are updated when the underlying data changes, but `ng-repeat` does not seem to work at all. It does not even render the first time, let alone update later. Simply appending the partial content I found does not seem to work at all: `element.append($(transcludedEl).find('.wrapper'));`

To illustrate my point, I have created a plunkr using three versions of the same code: http://plnkr.co/edit/xkAkzl8ID3m5Ras3Ww31

1. The first is super-simple direct ng-repeat, which only serves to show what should happen.
2. The second uses a directive that transcludes its full content, which works but is not what I need.
3. The third (reproduced below) uses a directive to try and include only part of its content, which is what I need, but which does not work.

The interesting bit is this:

```
app.directive('stickyPartial', ['$compile', '$timeout', function($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
          transclude(scope, function(transcludedEl) {
            // this is what i want to achieve - not working          
//            element.append($(transcludedEl).find('.wrapper'));

            // neither is this, though it does support expressions
            $compile($(transcludedEl).find('.wrapper'))(scope, function(clone) {
              element.append(clone);
            });
          });
        }
    };
}]);
```

So far, I have tried several combinations of `$compile`, `.clone()` and `.html()`, but to no avail. I can neither get a working partial DOM tree from the compiled template, nor a useful partial HTML source with `ng-repeat` intact that I can then compile manually.

As a last resort, I might try copying the DOM after angular is done (which seemed to work, previously) and then manually repeat this process every time the relevant model data changes. If there is another way, thought, I'd very much like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/24729270/2029017 I found a solution with `compile` that does what I want: http://plnkr.co/edit/V4yUbiAD9EAaaJXihziv